# Chararacterization of a triangle for which $R(b+c)=a\sqrt{bc}$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

My approach is as follow

It is given that $R(b+c)=a\sqrt{bc}$

We know that $R=\frac{abc}{4\triangle}$

On solving we get $\frac{abc}{4\triangle}(b+c)=a\sqrt{bc}$

Which is $\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{4}(b+c)=\triangle$  but not able to solve.

Comment: Please can I have my loudspeaker back? But seriously, please don't write in capitals...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am just repeating a complaint that has been made before by many others on this site also...

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change the title of your question in order it describes well the content of the question (I don't think mentionning "circumradius" in the title is necessary). Do you agree ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $R=\frac{a\sqrt{bc}}{b+c}$. By the sine law, we also have $R=\frac{a}{2\sin A}$. Equating these two, we get that $$\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{b+c}=\frac{1}{\sin A}\cdots \star$$
Note that the left hand side is positive, so we have $\sin A>0$, and as $0 < \sin A\leq 1$, we have $\frac{1}{\sin A}\geq 1$. Then, we have $\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{b+c}\geq 1$, and $b-2\sqrt{bc}+c=(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2\leq 0$. Since squares are nonnegative, we conclude that $b=c$. Plugging it back to $\star$, we have $\frac{1}{\sin A}=\frac{2b}{2b}=1$, and $\sin A=1$, so $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$. That is, triangle $\rm ABC$ is an right angled isosceles triangle.

Edit) You could also solve it using the area method you have tried. You have shown that $\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{4}(b+c)=S$, where $S$ denotes the area of the triangle. By AM-GM inequality, we have $b+c\geq 2\sqrt{bc}$, and we get $S\geq \frac{(\sqrt{bc})^2}{2}=\frac{bc}{2}$. On the other hand, we have $S=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A$. This gives $\sin A=1$, and the rest is the same as above.

Comment: I have also used the AM-GM inequality in my answer, but without connection to areas.

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=\frac{b}{\sin(B)}=\frac{c}{\sin(C)}=2R$$

the given equation is equivalent to :

$$2R^2(\sin(B)+\sin(C))=2R \sin(A) 2R \sqrt{\sin(B)\sin(C)}$$

which can be written under the form :

$$\underbrace{\frac12(\sin(B)+\sin(C))}_{\text{Arithmetical mean}}= \underbrace{\sin(A)}_{\le 1}\underbrace{\sqrt{\sin(B)\sin(C)}}_{\text{Geometrical mean}}\tag{1}$$

As the arithmetical mean of two positive quantities $p$ and $q$ is always bigger than their geometrical mean, with equality if and only if $p=q$,  the only possible issue for (1) to hold is that :

$$\begin{cases}\sin(A)=1 \implies A=\frac{\pi}{2} \ \text{and} \\  \sin(B)=\sin(C) \implies B=C \ (\text{because} \ B+C=\frac{\pi}{2})\end{cases}$$

which corresponds to the right isosceles triangle case (answer (C)).